# How could gevent socket block only the current greenlet?

Tags: python, sockets, gevent

I'm reading `gevent.socket` but I don't understand.

```
def recv(self, *args):
    sock = self._sock  # keeping the reference so that fd is not closed during waiting
    while True:
        try:
            return sock.recv(*args)
        except error, ex:
            if ex[0] == EBADF:
                return ''
            if ex[0] != EWOULDBLOCK or self.timeout == 0.0:
                raise
            # QQQ without clearing exc_info test__refcount.test_clean_exit fails
            sys.exc_clear()
        try:
            wait_read(sock.fileno(), timeout=self.timeout, event=self._read_event)
        except error, ex:
            if ex[0] == EBADF:
                return ''
            raise
```

The `sock` in `recv` is an instance of `_realsocket(family, type, proto)`. And in socket.py I found:

```
import _socket
_realsocket = _socket.socket
```

What is _socket? Why wouldn't `return sock.recv(*args)` block the whole program?

Answer (score 1):

The _socket is a standard c library of python which provides the real network communication,
and socket.py (in standard library or gevent) wrap methods up for common using.

Then, look into **init** of class Socket in gevent.socket,

````
```self._sock.setblocking(0)```
````

this statement make the socket object nonblocking